# iOS blueTooth BLE connects to device but show services null

Tags: ios, service, core-bluetooth

I am connecting to a blueTooth system http://redbearlab.com/blemini/

to read some data from a service,

how can I see the services available for this device,
I have checked using [lightblue ios app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue/id557428110?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4) that my device have services.

I can connect to my device, and get name,

but my services array appear as null [checked is not null with above app]

here my code

```
#import "MainViewController.h"



@interface MainViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, retain)UILabel *deviceName;
@property (nonatomic, retain)UILabel *deviceUUID;
@property (nonatomic, retain)UILabel *deviceConnected;


@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_deviceName release];
    [_deviceUUID release];
    [_deviceConnected release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self initUI];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    NSLog(@"mgmt");

    self.manager = [[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
}



- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {

    NSLog(@"centralManagerDidUpdateState");

    switch (central.state) {
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:

            // Scans for any peripheral
            [self.manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];

            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Central Manager did change state");
            break;
    }
}

// device discovered
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {


    NSLog (@"Discovered peripheral: %@", [peripheral name]);
    NSLog (@"UUID peripheral: %@", [peripheral UUID]);

    NSLog (@"peripheral services: %@", [peripheral services]);


    self.deviceName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Name: %@", [peripheral name]];
    self.deviceUUID.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device UUID: %@",[peripheral UUID]];

    [self.manager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}




//scan for peripherals
- (int) scanForPeripherals {

    NSLog(@"scanForPeripherals");

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];
    [self.manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];
    return 0;
}


- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
    NSLog(@"Central Manager didConnectPeripheral");


    self.deviceConnected.text = @"Device Connected: YES";

    NSLog (@"UUID services: %@", [peripheral services]);


    // Clears the data that we may already have
    [self.data setLength:0];
    // Sets the peripheral delegate
    [self.activePeripheral setDelegate:self];
    // Asks the peripheral to discover the service

//test! direct
    CBUUID  *serviceUUID    = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"D298E274-3CB0-2C5F-A0B0-A90D97304453"];
    NSArray *serviceArray   = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:serviceUUID, nil];

    [self.activePeripheral discoverServices:serviceArray];



}



- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)aPeripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"didDiscoverServices");


    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error discovering service: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        //[self cleanup];
        return;
    }

}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService");

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error discovering characteristic: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        //[self cleanup];
        return;
    }

}

//
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic");

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error changing notification state: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }


}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

So please advice on to why my services array is null?
and how to access it to "read" thanks!

Comment: Try: `[self.activePeripheral discoverServices:nil]` to discover all services.
Then in `didDiscoverServices`, NSLog the peripheral services.
Other possibility: Reboot the iDevice/Sensor Switch on/off the Bluetooth on the iDevice. Sometimes my app doesn't want to discover services. It just got stuck. Don't know why yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your property self.activePeripheral with the peripheral you get in didDiscoverPeripheral. Your code is discovering services for a peripheral that is null, thats why you get no services.